# Stop geolocation service windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, geolocation

I am doing an app for WP8, that uses Geo-location in background execution, 
and my code is located here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935(v=vs.105).aspx

All works fine when it is running in the background, the app show a toast saying where the phone is... but I have no idea how I can stop the background service, from the user perspective.

Answer (score 0):

To stop background tasks as a user:

1. go to **settings**
2. on top you can see "**System**" **slide right** to "**Application**"
3. open "**background tasks**"

There is also "advanced" for the ones the user can't stop.

Comment: i want to say inside the app , how i can programming ?